# Generic extension methods using where T : Interface

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, extension-methods

Does these 2 extension methods are the same or is there some danger in using 1 of the 2

```
public static T  GetSomthingFromListOf<T>(this List<T> list)where T: IMyInterface
{
    //do somthing that returns an item of T
}
```

Versus

```
public static IMyInterface GetSomthingFromList(this List<IMyInterface> list)
{
    //do somthing that returns an item of IMyInterface
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real difference is in the return type, the first one will return the type itself and constrain it so that it has to implement `IMyInterface`, and the second will just return the `IMyInterface` instance.

The second is useful for when you just want to expose the interface's members; the first is good for when you **need** to return the original type, but make sure that you can treat it in the method as an `IMyInterface`.

Comment: Nicely explained, didn't thought about the fact that in the second implementation I can only use the interface members. while in the first Example I can use all the members, it's just needs to be of type IMyInterface.
So I need in my problem the first one :).

Comment: @Clint: what if `T` is a struct?

Comment: @apocalypse I didn't never need a struct with an interface, but what could be the problem if it is a struct?

Comment: @apocalypse I'm not sure off the top of my head, but it should still work the same way, as structs can implement interfaces, but can't derive from a base class.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Clint answer:

1) if you have instance of `List<ConcreteType>` - only generic extension method will be available

2) if you pass `struct` as a parameter to non-generic method which expects interface - boxing will occur